# ファイルの書き出しができません！

Tags: java

下のプログラムはは3つのファイル(txt1,txt2,txt3)を読み込んでコンソールに出力し、別の3つ(txt4,txt5,txt6)のファイルを作って書き込むプログラムです。コンソールには出力され、ファイルも作られるのですが、ファイルの中身が3つとも"null"となってしまいます。なぜでしょうか？

```
 import java.io.*;

class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {     
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt1.txt"));
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt2.txt"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt3.txt"));

String line;

while( null !=(line=reader.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

String line1;
while( null !=(line1=reader1.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line1);
}

String line2;

while( null !=(line2=reader2.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line2);
}

reader.close();
reader1.close();
reader2.close();

File file=new File("txt4.txt");
File file1=new File("txt5.txt");
File file2=new File("txt6.txt");
file.createNewFile();
file1.createNewFile();
file2.createNewFile();
PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
PrintWriter writer1=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1)));
PrintWriter writer2=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2)));

writer.println(line);
writer1.println(line1);
writer2.println(line2);

writer.close();
writer1.close();
writer2.close();
}

catch(IOException e) {}

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

例えば変数 `line` について見てみると、

```java
String line;

while( null !=(line=reader.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

`line` が `null` でない限り上記の `while` ループ内の処理を実行し続けます。
逆にいうと、 `while` ループを抜けたとき、 `line` は必ず `null` です。

ですので、後続の処理

```java
writer.println(line);
```

を実行するときの `line` の値も当然 `null` です。

---

```java
while( null !=(line=reader.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

でコンソールに出力している値をファイルに書き出したいので、ファイル出力もここで行ってしまえばよいでしょう。

```java
import java.io.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt1.txt"));
            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt2.txt"));
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt3.txt"));
            
            File file = new File("txt4.txt");
            File file1 = new File("txt5.txt");
            File file2 = new File("txt6.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            file1.createNewFile();
            file2.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
            PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1)));
            PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2)));


            String line;

            while (null != (line = reader.readLine())) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.println(line);
            }

            String line1;
            while (null != (line1 = reader1.readLine())) {
                System.out.println(line1);
                writer1.println(line1);
            }

            String line2;

            while (null != (line2 = reader2.readLine())) {
                System.out.println(line2);
                writer2.println(line2);
            }

            reader.close();
            reader1.close();
            reader2.close();



            writer.close();
            writer1.close();
            writer2.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```